Gstreamer- I want to toggle between audio and video from the same src file present in the local directory
I've been trying to toggle between video and audio. Requirement: Play only the video (without the audio) for the first 3 seconds then play the audio and finish the audio till eos and finally resume the video from the 3rd second. For this I tried using the valve element to close off the audio then the video but somehow both video and audio plays simultaneously.
#include <gst/gst.h>

GstElement *pipeline, *source, *demux, *audio_queue, *video_queue, *audio_sink, *video_sink, *audio_valve, *video_valve;
GstPad *demux_audio_pad, *demux_video_pad, *demux_pad_template;

static gboolean audio_valve_open = TRUE;
static gboolean video_valve_open = FALSE;

static void pad_added_callback(GstElement *src, GstPad *new_pad, gpointer data) {
    GstPad *sink_pad;
    GstElement *queue = (GstElement *)data;
    GstCaps *new_pad_caps = NULL;
    GstStructure *new_pad_struct = NULL;
    const gchar *new_pad_type;

    g_print("Received new pad '%s' from '%s':\n", GST_PAD_NAME(new_pad), GST_ELEMENT_NAME(src));

    // Check the pad's type
    new_pad_caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps(new_pad);
    new_pad_struct = gst_caps_get_structure(new_pad_caps, 0);
    new_pad_type = gst_structure_get_name(new_pad_struct);

    // If it's audio, link it to the audio_queue
    if (g_str_has_prefix(new_pad_type, "audio/x-raw")) {
        g_print("Audio pad added\n");
        sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(audio_queue, "sink");
        gst_pad_link(new_pad, sink_pad);
    } else if (g_str_has_prefix(new_pad_type, "video/x-raw")) {
        // If it's video, link it to the video_queue
        g_print("Video pad added\n");
        sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(video_queue, "sink");
        GstPadLinkReturn ret = gst_pad_link(new_pad, sink_pad);
        if (ret != GST_PAD_LINK_OK) {
            g_error("Failed to link demux video pad to video queue pad. Error: %s",                                 
            gst_pad_link_get_name(ret));
        }
    }

    if (new_pad_caps != NULL)
        gst_caps_unref(new_pad_caps);
}

static gboolean switch_to_video(gpointer data) {
    g_print("Switching to Video...\n");
    // Close audio valve
    gst_element_set_state(audio_valve, GST_STATE_NULL);
    audio_valve_open = FALSE;
    // Open video valve
    gst_element_set_state(video_valve, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    video_valve_open = TRUE;
    return FALSE; // Don't call this function again
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    GstBus *bus;
    GstMessage *msg;

    // Initialize GStreamer
    gst_init(&argc, &argv);

    // Create the pipeline
    pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("pipeline");

    // Create elements
    source = gst_element_factory_make("filesrc", "source");
    demux = gst_element_factory_make("decodebin", "demux");
    audio_queue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "audio_queue");
    video_queue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "video_queue");
    audio_sink = gst_element_factory_make("alsasink", "audio_sink");
    video_sink = gst_element_factory_make("autovideosink", "video_sink");
    audio_valve = gst_element_factory_make("valve", "audio_valve");
    video_valve = gst_element_factory_make("valve", "video_valve");

    // Check elements creation
    if (!pipeline || !source || !demux || !audio_queue || !video_queue || !audio_sink || !video_sink || !audio_valve || !video_valve) {
        g_error("Failed to create elements. Exiting.");
        return -1;
    }

    // Set the location of the file to play
    g_object_set(source, "location", "/home/lg/ml/new.webm", NULL);

    // Add elements to the pipeline
    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(pipeline), source, demux, audio_queue, video_queue, audio_sink, video_sink, audio_valve, video_valve, NULL);

    // Link elements
    gst_element_link(source, demux);
    gst_element_link_many(audio_queue, audio_valve, audio_sink, NULL);
    gst_element_link_many(video_queue, video_valve, video_sink, NULL);

    // Connect pad-added signal
    g_signal_connect(demux, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(pad_added_callback), NULL);

    // Start playing
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    // Wait for 5 seconds to switch to video
    g_timeout_add_seconds(5, switch_to_video, NULL);

    // Listen for messages on the pipeline's bus
    bus = gst_element_get_bus(pipeline);
    msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE, GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

    // Free resources
    gst_message_unref(msg);
    gst_object_unref(bus);
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref(pipeline);

    return 0;
}



This is the code am using to demux audio video and stream a file in local directory location: /home/lg/ml/new.webm
After running the code I get the file played perfectly fine with video+audio none of the valve conditions were met.

g_timeout_add_seconds is designed to work with GMainLoop. In your case, you don't have a GMainLoop running, and your switch_to_video function is never called.
In your example, adding
g_main_loop_run(g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE));

after your g_timeout_add_seconds call does the work.
Now, in your switch_to_video() function, you should probably set the "drop" property of the valve instead:
g_object_set(audio_valve, "drop", 1, NULL); //Start dropping frames

Following your code, this will"turn off the audio" after 5 seconds.
You can also use g_object_get to get the current value of the drop property (to easily toggle on and off).
Finally, your code will not really match what you describe. I'll let you play with the drop property to achieve exactly what you want.
